# website setting in a database table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am building a CMS,

The CMS information is stored in a `mysql` `database` inside a `table` called `cms_settings`

[image: cms_settings table]

I want to get the `setting_value` and store it to a variable, for example:

```
$cms_url = ?;
$cms_theme = ?;
```

I've tried to use the `mysqli_fetch_array()` but I couldn't make it right.

```
<?php

require('db.php');

$s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cms_settings");
$i = mysqli_fetch_array($s);
foreach($i as $key=>$value)
{
  $cms_url = $i[0][2];
}
?>
```

but that didn't work!

your help is highly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your results. Maybe try something like this:

```
<?php

require('db.php');

$settings = array();
$s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cms_settings");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) {
      $settings[$row['setting_name']] = $row['setting_value'];
}
```

edit: added saving your settings into an array.

edit2: If you want to get specific settings, maybe put it in a function.

```
function getSetting($name) {
    require('db.php');

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);

    $s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE `setting_name` = '{$name}'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s)) {
        return $row['setting_value'];
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, BUT I am getting the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in...`

Comment: woops, no new keyword in front of array!

Comment: Great, this will output all the rows, but how can I grap a specific setting value? like the cms_url value and save it to $cms_url variable by using the row index.

Comment: If you want a specific setting probably the easiest thing to do is to change your query to: `$s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE setting_name = 'cms_url'");` This will only return the specific row.

Comment: Yes, this will work but if I have a 100 settings then I have to have a 100 query!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63234/discussion-between-sultan-and-bas-slats).

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you array is $I and your foreach loop is looping through the $key=>value, but in your foreach you are still referencing $i.

Instead, do this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($s))  {
     $cms_url = $row['cms_url'];
}
```

**EDIT:**

A foreach loop in this case would not be ideal as you would battle to give each result a unique variable name as a foreach loop will loop through each array item and apply the required tasks to the current value

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array named 'cms_settings' and fill the array with the keys from your result

```
 <?php
    require('db.php');

    $s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cms_settings");
    $i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);
    $cms_settings= array();

    foreach($i as $row)
    {
      $cms_settings[$row['setting_name']] = $row['setting_value'];
    }

    /* show a setting */
    echo 'CMS url is: '.$cms_settings['cms_url'];

    /* show all settings */
    print_r($cms_settings);

 ?>
```

Comment: Your snippet cannot work as there is no database to connect to, so you have basically shown a blank snippet

Comment: ? It's an improved version of the code of the question.

Comment: What I'm saying is when you click on "Run code snippet", the code window is blank because there is no database, should rather just put the code in code blocks

Comment: Thanks, BUT It returns `Notice: Undefined index: cms_url in...`

Comment: What is the output of "print_r($cms_settings)"

Comment: `CMS url is: Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => cms_url [setting_name] => cms_url [2] => http://www. [setting_value] => http://www. )`

Comment: didn't work, I got `Warning: Illegal string offset 'setting_name' in..` and `Notice: Undefined index: cms_url in...` and the output of `print_r($cms_settings);` is `CMS url is: Array ( [1] => 1 [c] => c [h] => h )`

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array